# Problem with dual boot with Windows 8.

Tags: installation, dual-boot

Ubuntu installs correctly, but then when I boot computer no Ubuntu boot option appears.

I am not very familiar with Linux systems, but when I install Ubuntu using a USB it says that everything installed correctly. Then when I restart the computer no boot menu appears to boot Ubuntu. Instead the computer boots straight to Windows.

Do I need to install Grub2 or something to bring up a boot menu?

I've looked at the other forums for an answer to this question and they haven't helped.

Comment: Does your system supported UEFI? (Is your PC recent?)

Comment: If computer is pre-installed Windows 8 then it is UEFI with gpt partitioning. You need to go into UEFI and choose to boot the ubuntu option. You may need to run Boot-Repair to fix a grub bug in that os-prober will not add correct boot entries for Windows to the grub menu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do need to install a boot loader. Otherwise the mbr will contain windows loader code which runs straight into windows. Please take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) and [here](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu%3aAll#Dual-Booting_Windows_and_Ubuntu) for the proper procedures absically all you need is to do is install a new boot manager.